# Creating Python class with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, class

I apologize for the newbie question, but this is my first time working with classes. The class I'm trying to create is intended to perform a regex find and replace on all keys and values within a dictionary. The specific find and replace is defined upon instantiation.

There are two issues that I have. The first issue is that each instance of the class needs to accept a new dictionary. I'm not clear on how to create a class that accepts a general dictionary which I can specify upon creating an instance.
The second issue is that the class I have simply isn't working. I'm receiving the error message `TypeError: expected string or buffer` in the class line `v = re.sub(self.find,self.replace,v)`.

There are three instances I want to create, one for each input dictionary: `input_iter1`, `input_iter2`, and `input_iter3`.

The following is the class:

```
class findreplace:
    values = []
    keys = []
    def __init__(self, find, replace):
        self.find = find
        self.replace = replace
    def value(self):
        for k,v in input_iter1.items():
            v = re.sub(self.find,self.replace,v)
            findreplace.values.append(v)
    def key(self):
        for k,v in input_iter1.items():
            k = re.sub(self.find,self.replace,k)
            findreplace.keys.append(k)
```

The following are the instances:

```
values1 = findreplace('[)?:(]','')
values1.value()
values2 = findreplace(r'(,\s)(,\s)(\d{5})({e<=1})',r'\2\3')
values2.value()
keys1 = findreplace(r'(?<=^)(.+)(?=$)',r'(?:\1)')
keys1.key()
keys2 = findreplace(r'(?=$)',r'{e}')
keys2.key()

print values
print keys
```

If anyone has any insight on how I can workaround these two issues, I'd be grateful to hear them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Python 2 classes should start off this way:

```
class Foo(object):
```

Otherwise, you get an "old-style class", which is some ancient crusty thing no one uses.

Also, class names in Python are typically written in `CamelCase`.

Second, **do not** use mutable values (like lists!) as class attributes, as you're doing here with `keys` and `values`.  They'll be shared across all instances of your class!  It looks like you're even aware of this, since you refer to `findreplace.keys` directly, but it doesn't make sense to store instance-specific values in a class attribute like that.

But, most importantly: why is this a class at all?  What does a `findreplace` *represent*?  It looks like this would be much clearer if it were just a single function.

---

To answer your actual questions:

1. You pass in a dictionary just like you're passing in `find` and `replace`.  Add another argument to `__init__`, and pass another argument when you construct your class.
2. Presumably, you're getting the `TypeError` because one of the values in your dictionary isn't a string, and you can only perform regexes on strings.

Comment: I thought a creating a class may be better because it would otherwise get exceedingly verbose, but if you think I would be better off simply using functions, I'll take that as an acceptable answer. Thanks for the detailed reply.

Comment: as a rule of thumb, if i can't explain to someone else what an instance of some class **is** (not "does"!) in ten words or fewer, it shouldn't be a class  :)  a lot of awkward classes force me to start off with "it's an object that..." which uses up most of my words already

Answer (score 1):

Where is your definition of the  input_iter dicts?  How do they look like? Your error indicates that the values of your dicts are not strings.